# opencart 2.1.0.2-save percent in category.php & issue with pagination/filters

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I have implemented the following code in category.php to display percentage of sale price between price and special price. And it works fine but...when I sort, choose a filter (product option filtering) or go to the second page of pagination, the percentage disappears! I guess I have to write the code in another spot or add it to the pagination/filter/sort somewhere....

```
 if (count($additional_images) > 0) {
                $image2 = $this->model_tool_image->resize($additional_images[0]['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height'));$image = $image .'" id="category_'.$result['product_id'].'"';
            }

            //sale % mod
            $specialSavings      = round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'])*100, 0);
            if ( $specialSavings  >= 23 && $specialSavings <= 27 )


                  {
                    $specialSavings = 25;
                  }
            elseif ( $specialSavings  > 27)

                  {
                    $specialSavings = 30;  

                  }
                  elseif ( $specialSavings  < 23)
                  {
                    $specialSavings = 20;  
                  }
                   else {
                $specialSavings = false;

            }
            //sale % mod
```

and

```
data['products'][] = array('specialSavings'      => $specialSavings,//sale % mod
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!